# need Simple JS text inside tags editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor

help me to find JS text editor like on my screenshot.

http://prntscr.com/3qior4

It must have next features:

1. Show html tags
2. Change tags color to grey (or any color)
3. Can edit text inside html tags
4. Can't edit or delete html tags.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any investigation on finding a HtML editor that prevents user from changing HTML tags.

If you wish to block for isntance, a traductor from changing tags and focus only on text, then you should use some internationalisation librairy (like i118) and give to the traductor only the text output to modify.

If you look for a very smple interface for coding HTML, use adobe dreamweaver : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver

If you look for a custo synthax color, you can use some templates for Notepad++ or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**SynWrite** editor with additional setup. Activate HTML lexer, then open html lexer properties dialog, find lexer rule for `<tag>` text, and change style for this rule. Changed style must have Read-only attribute set.

Refer to synwrite forum.